# Slow printing using Windows Server 2008 easyprint, Lexmark example

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

Morning,

We're currently in a project of moving a big customer (~300 users) from a Server 2003 terminal server environment to a 2008 to get around Tricerat licenses and some other old software.

Earlier we've used Tricerat's "Screwdriver" to manage printing from inside the terminal server to the clients printer, but now we're planning on using Easyprint instead.

My questions are more or less, how does Easyprint really work, does the terminal server have local drivers of all known printers or are they just being redirected without the need for a driver?

Currently we're trying out a Lexmark e330 and it takes more then 5 (!) minutes to print a paper, compared to 25 seconds locally.
We've also tried a Dell 2145 and that prints instantly doing the same procedure.
What could cause this? Is there a way around or anything other I need to know?

The problem is that all 300 clients use their own printers, so I can't possibly install them one by one nor can I tell them to upgrade.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't messed around with either application so I'm no help there...

Long print times are directly related to using a redirected driver rather than a local server driver. You can migrate printer services roles from one server to another, however your largest obstacle doing that is if your 2003 server was 32 bit and you are moving to W2K8 x64, as the drivers aren't compatible.

I would honestly suggest a hybrid environment, keeping both active, until you can reinstall all the printers on the new server.

Good printer design is trying to keep large corporate installs same model number. (small personal color for execs, and MFPs for common. That was you install ~4 print drivers and just add all the specified network ports.